# update app on playstore with appypie certificate

Tags: android, google-play

at my work they have an app which they made using appypie
so now we create a native app so for me I create the android app and now I tried to update the existing one with new apk
so I made the package name , vertion name and vertion code.. ets. everything compatible but google play now refuse the app only because of this reason:

> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to
>   your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing
>   APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s): [ SHA1:
>   55:A4:8E:1A:17:A0:67:C7:FB:22:EF:B3:63:95:58:EA:C0:FC:31:3F ] and the
>   certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
>   [ SHA1: 03:95:F7:78:3A:6F:1C:0F:A8:4C:57:05:36:9B:F4:C4:10:A2:AE:C6 ]

after contact the appypie they give us the keystore alias name and keystore Password so I create new jks file with same alias and password then build the apk with it
but google still give me the same error of certificate so I contact them and they give me a binary file and told me to get the .jks file from it
so how can do this?

or if there are another solutions for this problem so help me please

Answer (score 1):

You created a new jks file.  Don't do that.  You need to use the same jks file, not a new jks with the same alias.  If you use a new jks file, you have a different signing key.

If you don't have the original jks file, if you have Google App Signing on, you can just contact Google about the new key.  If you don't, you're in for pain-  google can reset your app to use a new key, but nobody who previously downloaded your app will be able to upgrade without uninstalling.

Comment: okay I understand you now they give me a file and told me to get the jks from it by using this command: `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore {{_Path_of_Keystore_}} {{_Path_Of_sing_apk_}} -storepass keystore Password  -keypass keystore Password keystore alias name`

I have the keystore Password and keystore alias name but I can't understand the Path_of_Keystore and Path_Of_sing_apk @Gabe Sechan

Comment: Path of key site is the jks file. The other is the powerful of the apk

Comment: I don't have the jks file they give me this command in order to get the jks file from it so I add the path for the old apk of appypie and the Path_of_Keystore what should it be since there is no old jks? @Gabe Sechan

Comment: Without the old jks file you're screwed. That's the command to sign an unsigned apk with a jks file